# IONotificationPortCreate not working in Swift

Tags: swift

Trying to do some Swift stuff.  Converting some **USB** device detection code from Objective-C to Swift.  Having a problem with getting the `Notification` port.  `IONotificationPortCreate` returns a `Unmanaged<'IONotificationPort'>!` and when the program runs it hangs on line 2 below and I then printed out the description of notify and notifyPort below.  I don't know if it's not getting the port or if I'm not getting it out of that `Unmanaged <'IONotificationPort'>!` correctly or something else is wrong

```
var notify = IONotificationPortCreate(kIOMasterPortDefault)

var notifyPort = notify.takeRetainedValue() as IONotificationPortRef
```

Printing description of notify: `(Unmanaged<'IONotificationPort'>!) notify = (_value = <no summary available>)`

Printing description of notifyPort: `(IONotificationPortRef) notifyPort = 0x000000010050e620 {}`

Thanks for any help,

Chris